# Kafka consumer offset max value?

Tags: offset, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I was googling and reading Kafka documentation but I couldn't find out the max value of a consumer offset and whether there is offset wraparound after max value.
I understand offset is an Int64 value so max value is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. 
If there is wraparound, how does Kafka handle this situation?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

According to this [post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-kafka-users/201111.mbox/%3CCAFbh0Q3wXeivW9G+xre5eN8-SLVprdNLWyKmd+CcW6n=A=ZSHQ@mail.gmail.com%3E), the offset is not reset:

> We don't roll back offset at this moment. Since the offset is a long, it
>   can last for a really long time. If you write 1TB a day, you can keep going
>   for about 4 million days.
>
> Plus, you can always use more partitions (each partition has its own
>   offset).

So as Luciano said, probably not worth worrying about.

Comment: Yup.  Just like Y2K  :)

Comment: I think we'll have to worry about it in the following 10 years.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this is not really "handled". But, taking into account that the offset is per partition, it seems this is something we should not worry about :)

Please see http://search-hadoop.com/m/uyzND1uRn8D1sSH322/rollover/v=threaded