# Max number of messages that can be stored in a Kafka topic partition?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a retention policy set for 48 hours. So old logs are eventually flushed. But topic's offset number keeps growing. When does this number get reset? What happens when the max offset number is reached? Also, new segments are rolled with base offset as filename at the time of creating new segment.What will be the filenames of .log and .index files when this limit is reached?

The following is the current base offset for log segment :
[image: current base offset for log segment]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kafka consumer offset max value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408970/kafka-consumer-offset-max-value)

Comment: OP is asking when the offset is reset on account of an exceeded retention time, not what the actual max value of the offset is. Not a duplicate of suggested question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The offset is never reset because the max offset value is so big (int64) that you won't ever reach it.

Comment: A meager 292 years and it flips over if you create a message every nano second. :-)